# Angularjs ui-router state data on initial load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My routes are like so:

```
...
.state('some.route', {
    url: '/some/route',
    template: 'someTemplate.html',
    controller: 'SomeCtrl'
    data: {
        title: 'Some Title'
    }
})
...
```

Every route has a `data.title` property.

I also have a directive like so

```
...
app.directive('titleBar', function($state, $rootScope){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.title = $state.current.data.title; // On initial load, find data.title and bind it
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState){
                scope.title = toState.data.title; // On state change, bind new data.title
            }
        },
        template: '<div class="title-bar"> {{ title }} </div>'
    };
});
```

When you navigate states, the directive works fine and binds the appropriate title.

But when I do a full refresh, it doesn't return the right data for the state I refreshed in. Instead it returns some sort of abstract base state like so:

```
console.log($state.current);
>>>> OUTPUT
{
    abstract: true,
    name: "",
    url: "^",
    views: null
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you set this `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(someurl)' or any .when()

Comment: @AnkitLadhania Yeah, I set an `$urlRouterProvider.when('foo','bar')`

Comment: and the url are you are going to lies within your when() and states

Comment: @AnkitLadhania I have `.when('/user/:id', '/users/profile/:userId');` and `.when('/u?id', '/users/profile/:userId')`. The route that I'm testing and is `/users/dashboard` but it happens with any route really.

Comment: The state that you are getting is the [root state](http://slides.com/timkindberg/ui-router#/11/1) that is the topmost state. every state that you create is the child of that.

Comment: can you create a plnkr

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out why this is happening, and am still trying to find a solution.

The directive is in the main layout, before the ui-view. So when you reload the page, the state will obviously be the root state, which then gets updated when the view loads.

SOLUTION UPDATE:

Instead of using `$on('$stateChangeStart')` I'm now using `$on('$viewContentLoaded')`.

Comment: hey @RCorrie can you help me with is question its also on AngularJs [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574008/is-not-letting-the-state-to-pass-to-usernamea-za-z0-93-20-in-angul)

Comment: did you find it i have linked it in my previous comment